# Getting php with js with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

It won't give me the value from $scoresArray in php to data_response in js
If I log (obj) it returns nothing.

I have this in JS

```
  $.ajax({
                url: "Database.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (obj) {
                  stageRef.$("txtTopscorePunt").html(obj.score[0]);
                  stageRef.$("txtTopscorePunt2").html(obj.score[1]);
                  stageRef.$("txtTopscorePunt3").html(obj.score[2]);
                }       
           });
```

This in php:

```
function GetScores(){           
        $query = "SELECT * FROM topscores ORDER BY Scores DESC LIMIT 3";
        $result = mysql_query($query);      

        $scoresArray = array(); 
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $scoresArray[$i]['score'] = $row['score'];
            $i++;
        }
        echo json_encode($scoresArray); 
    }
```

Comment: Either use `$.ajax({}).complete(data_response)` or use `success` rather than `complete` in that way.

Comment: so $.ajax({}).complete(data_response) var str = data_response;
      var obj = JSON.parse(str);
      stageRef.$("txtTopscorePunt").html(obj.score[0]);
      stageRef.$("txtTopscorePunt2").html(obj.score[1]);
      stageRef.$("txtTopscorePunt3").html(obj.score[2]);

Comment: What's the `stageRef.` supposed to do?

Comment: Please do NOT substantially change your question after it's already been answered.

Comment: stageRef is a link to my stage. I'm working with Adobe edge animate

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `JSON.parse(str)` with `dataType:json` -- it's already parsed.

In addition, your selectors are wrong. If you want to select an ID, you need the `#` character.

```
           $.ajax({
                url: "Database.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (obj) {   // not 'complete'
                    console.log(obj);
                    $("#txtTopscorePunt").html(obj.score[0]);
                    $("#txtTopscorePunt2").html(obj.score[1]);
                    $("#txtTopscorePunt3").html(obj.score[2]);
                }       
           });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I changed my code to yours (see above). But i don't get my log

Comment: If you open your PHP page directly in a browser, do you see the JSON data?

Comment: No, that's not it. It isn't a class or an id. Still the log doesn't return anything. I have updated other texts with stageRef.$("txtTopscorePunt").html(...) so that's right. I think the problem is with obj

Comment: I have no experience with Adobe Edge, so I'm unable to help you with that part.

Answer (score 0):

update the code to this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "Database.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data_response) {
                    console.log(data_response);
                    var response = data_response;
                    var response_str = JSON.stringify(response);
                    alert(response_str); // don't do this if the returned is too much
                    console.log(response_str); // use your browser console to view the results
                    }       
                });
```

Once you have done this, can you post the results of alert or console log.

Also, in the results does it start with "[" or "{"?

From the results we should be able to help you with the correct way to access your JSON object.

Regards.

Comment: Very strange, that still returns me nothing. And it's with [], if i try {} Adobe edge returns me an error

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Are you sure it's going in the "success:" can you add "error:" also.

Also can you try it with "GET" instead of "POST", as I can't find you posting any data to the link.

One more trick to debug, make the PHP file return a simple string first and try to catch that in Ajax.

let me know hoe it goes.

Comment: Yes error returns me something. But why does it go wrong? I tested the sql statemetns and they all work

Comment: Whats the error?

can you place debug statements in your PHP file?

Comment: Sorry, but can you please post the exact JS you are trying to run.
I will be able to tell you what's happening to variable `obj`